# Scroll to a "name" using Link

Tags: jquery, html

JQuery:

```
k = get the element that is being clicked on.
$('k').click(function() { //based on the element and where it should scroll to
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTo: /*target*/},800); /*target==where its scrolling to*/
});
```

HTML:

```
    <a id="a1" class="pointto">1</a>
    <a id="a2" class="pointto">2</a>
    <a id="a3" class="pointto">3</a>
    <a id="a4" class="pointto">4</a>
    <a id="a5" class="pointto">5</a>

    <a name="1">1. This is where it scrolls to</a>
    <a name="2">2. This is where it scrolls to</a>
    <a name="3">3. This is where it scrolls to</a>
    <a name="4">4. This is where it scrolls to</a>
    <a name="5">5. This is where it scrolls to</a>
```

What I am looking to accomplish is to use the single "click()" function to scroll to the respected link target.

Example, if `a1` is clicked, scroll to `1`. If `a2` is clicked, scroll to `2` and so forth...

I am using all this code in my page and I get an error if I add the `click()` function below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#theEmail').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.match(/[^\-_a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\-_a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
        }
    });
    $(".pointto").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("Hover");
    });
    $(".pointto").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("Hover").removeClass("Pressed");
    });
    $(".pointto").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).addClass("Pressed");
    });
    $(".pointto").mouseup(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("Pressed");
    });
    $('.pointto').click(function() { 
        var nn = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
        var top = $('a[name='"+nn+"']').offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:top},800);
    });
});
```

`Error: Expected ')' in line: var top = $('a[name='"+nn+"']').offset().top;`

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I did each one individually, which takes up a lot of lines.

Comment: Will it always be of the form 'a' plus a number?

Comment: Yes, it's always always a#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.pointto').click(function() { 
    var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('a',''),
    t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:t},800);
});
```

If you change the classes you have to use event delegation. Instead of `(document)` you can use a static selector, like one of the parents of those links

```
$(document).on('click', '.Hover, .Pressed, .pointto', function() { 
    var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('a',''),
    t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:t},800);
});
```

Comment: And if you'll be dynamically changing the list of links, you can do `$('.pointto-list').on('click', '.pointto', function(){...}))`, where `.pointto-list` is a selector to find the list of links.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will test it out now.

Comment: I have other functions which is using `.pointto' and it's causing an error. I update my question with what else I am using.

Comment: @SiKni8 you should keep a class only for JS to make it easier, but try with `on()`

Comment: I get an `offset().top is null or not an object' error with your error code.

Comment: @SiKni8 sorry, it's because of `parseInt()`. Apparently it won't work if the first char is not a number. Try the `on()` with `replace()` or `substr()`

Comment: @Spokey I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this the "right" way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7wr7G/

html:

```
<a href="#1" class="pointto">1</a>
<a href="#2" class="pointto">2</a>
<a href="#3" class="pointto">3</a>
<a href="#4" class="pointto">4</a>
<a href="#5" class="pointto">5</a>
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<a name="1">1. This is where it scrolls to</a>
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<a name="2">2. This is where it scrolls to</a>
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<a name="3">3. This is where it scrolls to</a>
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<a name="4">4. This is where it scrolls to</a>
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<a name="5">5. This is where it scrolls to</a>
<div style="height: 900px;"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".pointto").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $("[name=" + this.href.split("#")[1] + "]").offset().top;
    $("body,html").animate({"scroll-top":target},800);
});
```

It allows for deep-linking/bookmarking and works with javascript disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but Wouldn't the URL have a `#` at the end?

Comment: Only if javascript is disabled, otherwise it wouldn't scroll without javascript or allow for easy deep linking.

Comment: I updated my question, can you see why I am receiving the error? Thanks

Comment: I dont' see anything wrong other than the quotes toward the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pointto').click(function () {
    target_name = $(this).attr('id').substr(1);
    target = $('a[name="' + target_name + '"]');

    $('body, html').animate({scrollTo: $(target).offset().top}, 800);
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxtXU/1)

Comment: -1 because `.substr(-1)` won't work if one of the links is `a10` or higher.

Comment: @Derek, sorry, i meant to write `substr(1)` thanks. i have updated

Comment: Works nice, except I want to animate the scrolling method. Thanks though :)

Comment: Sorry to have to edit your answer, but the system wouldn't let me remove my downvote even though you'd fixed your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pointto').click(function () {
    var target = this.id.replace('a', ''),
        offset = $('a[name="' + target + '"]').offset().top;
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 800);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAzhJ/2/)

Note: While I was typing this, several people beat me to the post, so I can delete if it's not useful.

Comment: I +1'ed anyway because you did answer. And every answer is useful but differently to different people... Thanks :)

Comment: With your code, I am getting the following error: `'offset().top' is null or not an object`

Comment: @SiKni8, thanks. I forgot to close off the click handler.  Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

after the name="1" add class="k"

in the jquery use $('a.k')...........

```
$('a.k').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                //if $(this).attr("name") = 1 do this
                //or use a jquery equivalent to a case statement
            });
        });
```